# Only starting in command mode after I tried installing nvidia drivers

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia

I had put in a new video card on the box and tried installing nvidia drivers version 173 via command line and *System ➜ Administration ➜ Additional Drivers*.

Now when I try to restart ubuntu 11.04 it is starting in command prompt mode.

What can I do to fix this or get the things back as they were?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem... I know I have nvidia hardware on this thing, but I didn't actively try to install any new drivers. What happens when you type "unity" into the prompt?

Comment: Have you tried typing `startx`? In the past when my boot has failed to start graphics, I found simply typing that to usually be a quick and simple solution.

Comment: Maybe a conflict with `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`? Try moving it away and reboot (`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf{,.back}`.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, I went into recovery and then failsafe graphics (your gfx is turned off) and then you uninstall the drivers. this should revert to how things were. =)